# tab not triggering in safari jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I'm trying to trigger first tab when opening a jquery dialog. It works in every browser but safari. Any ideas guys?

```
            $('.dialog').dialog({ resizable: false,  autoOpen: false, 'modal':true, 'width':900, 'height':500, 
              open: function(e,ui) {
              $('#container-1').triggerTab(0);
            });
```

This is working in every browser but safari I have also tried placing `return false;` after

`$('#container-1').triggerTab(0);`

but this does not work either.

I am using Klaus Hartl  tabs plugin any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog initiation does look incorrect. Try the following.

```
   $('.dialog').dialog({
        open: function(e, ui) {
            $('#container-1').triggerTab(0);
        },
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    });
```